# Drag website pages horizontally with Jquery

Tags: jquery, background, draggable

How can i achieve a dragable background like the bg of the site below using jquery?

> http://us.blackberry.com/

I found something very close,a jquery plugin [here.](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html) But it doesn't have option to drag. What will be the 
best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a jQuery-plugin that helps you build these:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dragscroller

But in theory, if you want to do it yourself, you would have to listen for the mouseDown, then, while that is active, listen for the mouseMovement on the x-axis to scroll (with jQuery.scrollLeft() for example) and mouseUp to end the event-chain.

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of swipe functionality. I would look into JQuery Mobile.